# Why have an array in a list? C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, search, logbook

I'm working on a logbook as an assignment in school and I've come as far as shown below. I'm struggling though with some things that needs to be implemented and my biggest concern is to understand why I need an array within the list.

I'm told to use:

```
List logBook = new List { };
string[]post = new string [2]
```

The function is that I'm suppose to be able to save new posts, with at least a Title and a message. The logbook is suppose to be a List and each log is suppose to be an array.

So my question is simply am I going in the right direction and can someone pls help me to understand why it has to be an array in the list. Also, feel free to help me in the right direction when it comes to the searchpart, I'd like to be able to search for either date, title or a single word in the post.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    string titel;
    string post;
    string[] logg = new string[20];

    List<string[]> logBook = new List<string[]> { };
    DateTime tiden = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine(tiden.ToShortDateString());

    bool go = true;

    while (go)
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\tWelcome to the Logbook!\n");
            Console.WriteLine("\t[1] Write a new post");
            Console.WriteLine("\t[2] Search for a post");
            Console.WriteLine("\t[3] Display all posts");
            Console.WriteLine("\t[4] Quit");
            Console.Write("\n\tSelect from menu: ");

            int menyVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int i = 0;

            switch (menyVal)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("\tWrite a title to your post: ");
                    titel= Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tWrite your post: ");

                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + tiden.ToShortDateString() + "\n");
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + titel + "\t");
                    post = Console.ReadLine();
                    logg[i] = tiden.ToShortDateString() + "\n" + titel + "\n" + post + "\n";
                    logBook.Add(logg);
                    i = i + 1;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("\tWrite a searchword or a date (yyyy-mm-dd)");
                    string keyword = Console.ReadLine();

                    foreach (var item in logBook)
                    {
                        if (logg[i] == keyword)
                            Console.WriteLine(logg[i]);
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine("Searchword couldn't be found.");
                    }
                    break;

                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("\tThese are the current posts in Logbook.\n ");
                    foreach (string[] element in logBook)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\t" + element);
                    }

                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("\tChoose from menu 1 - 4");
                    break;

                case 4:
                    go = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\tChoose from menu 1 - 4");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad and incomplete code but I wanted to give u a hint of what it's all about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like dasblinkenlight said, it's better to use a class. So i'll totally agree with him.

---

But....   For your solution. There is a problem with your list and arrays.

The way you implemented it is, you are using an array of strings and a list. You're writing the whole formatted string as one element of the array. And you add the whole array to the list. So each item in the list is the same array....

As far as i read your post, you should have a new array per list item. I've take a piece of code for example:

```
switch (menyVal)
{
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine("\tWrite a title to your post: ");
        // i'd rather declare the string here, so the code and declaration should stick together. (it's not the pascal language ;-))
        string titel= Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("\n\tWrite your post: ");

        Console.WriteLine("\t" + tiden.ToShortDateString() + "\n");
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + titel + "\t");
        post = Console.ReadLine();

        // here comes the thing:
        // you are formatting it as one element and add that element to the list. 
        // ->> wrong   >>   logg[i] = tiden.ToShortDateString() + "\n" + titel + "\n" + post + "\n";
        // ->> logBook.Add(logg);

        // create an array per item....
        string[] arr = new string[2];
        arr[0] = title;
        arr[1] = post;

        logBook.Add(arr);

        //   i = i + 1;   not needed.
        break;
```

This way the global `logg` array is not needed.. The list will keep a reference to the array that you add.

---

This is incorrect...    You iterating the logbook (list of arrays) and you're checking the same logitem over and over. (variable `i` never changes)

```
foreach (var item in logBook)
{
    if (logg[i] == keyword)
        Console.WriteLine(logg[i]);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Searchword couldn't be found.");
}
```

What you are looking for is:

```
van anyFound = false;

foreach (var item in logBook)
{
    foreach(var element in item)
    {
        if(element == keyword)
        {
            foreach(var s in item)
            {
                Console.Write(s);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
            anyFound = true;
        }
    }
    if(!anyFound)
        Console.WriteLine("Searchword couldn't be found.");
}
```

Or in short:

```
var foundIn = logBook.Where(item => item.Contains(keyword));

foreach(var elements in foundIn)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", elements);
```

**Feel free to ask more info**

Comment: Many thx to u Jeroen van Langen, u totally set me straight again. It seems so obvious when u see it before u.
Now, if I want a date in each post, is it easier to create an array of its own like arr[2] = time; and extend arr 
or to put it beside the title? 
What makes it better searchwise?

Comment: For storing a datetime for each logitem. You need to use the `DateTime.ToString()` method. Thats why you shouldnt use a string array and use a class instead. The problem with storing datetimes into strings is that you fix it to a locale. Culture specific format. Also you are losing information like seconds if you dont format them. **You might try it for this practice, but keep in mind that a class is a better practice.**

Comment: I sure will. I'm just about to struggle with the searchpart and implementation of date. All in all it all shows why I should use a class instead. It might be me but since I'm also asked to be able to edit a post and even remove specific posts it really seems like a class would be in hand and my formar question stands.....Why put an array in a list....all I can see is that you really are locking in all values in the arrayelements into a string in the list??

Comment: The idea of a list, is that you can add/remove items. The idea of an array is creating a fixed element count of the specified type. There is no direct reason to put an array into a list. The only reason I can think of is when you need to queue items (in this specific case). **For example a queue of packets (byte arrays) received from a socket. This queue would be usefull to transfer items between threads. So a receive thread that queues the packets (array of bytes) received from a socket onto the queue (`List<byte[]`), and another thread to handle the received packets. (which needs locking)**

Answer (score 3):

The idea to use a `List<T>` is correct. The idea to use an array of two strings, one for the title and one for the message, is not correct.

Although C# lets you store arrays in a list, the problem with storing two-element arrays is that the content of these arrays is not symmetric: `logBook[i][0]` is always a title, while `logBook[i][1]` is always a message.

It would be better to make a class for post, with `Title` and `Message` properties, and use it instead of an array:

```
class LogPost {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

A `List<LogPost>` is a lot more readable than a `List<string[]>`, and it lets you access `logBook[i].Title` and `logBook[i].Message` in a much more readable way.

Comment: Thx, I'll implement a two-element array and try. I agree with making a class but as it seems I'm suppose to use a list with arrays within.

Answer (score 0):

This is what it came down to in the end even if I haven't solved the thing with editing or change a log after it's written or even to remove a log aswell...I might be able to do it tomorrow :)

```
    List<string[]> logBook = new List<string[]> { };
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + time.ToShortDateString());
        Console.WriteLine("\n\tWelcome to the Logbook!\n");

        bool go = true;

        while (go)
            try
            {
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("");  //Skapar ny rad. Användaren ska inte känna att det blandar ihop sig.
                    Console.WriteLine("\t[1] Write a new post");
                    Console.WriteLine("\t[2] Search for a post");
                    Console.WriteLine("\t[3] Display all posts");
                    Console.WriteLine("\t[4] Quit");

                    Console.Write("\n\tSelect from menu: ");

                    int menu = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());  //Gör om inmatad sträng till heltal.
                    Console.WriteLine("");  //Skapar mellanrum innan nästa direktiv till användaren (Estetiskt).

                    switch (menu)
                    {
                        case 1:

                            string timeDate = time.ToShortDateString();

                            Console.Write("\tWrite a title to your post: ");
                            string title = Console.ReadLine();

                            Console.Write("\n\tPost is created " + timeDate + "\n\n\tWrite your post: ");

                            //Console.WriteLine("\t" + timeDate + "\n");
                            //Console.WriteLine("\t" + title + "\n\t");
                            string post = Console.ReadLine();

                            string[] arr = new string[3];
                            arr[0] = timeDate;
                            arr[1] = title;
                            arr[2] = post;

                            logBook.Add(arr);
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            Console.Write("\tWrite a searchword or a date (yyyy-mm-dd): ");
                            string keyword = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("");

                            bool anyFound = false;

                            foreach (string[] item in logBook)  //För varje element(item) i Listan(logBook) dvs (arr[i])
                            {
                                foreach (string element in item)  //För varje element(element) i arr[i] dvs (arr[0], arr[1], arr[2])
                                {
                                    if (element.Contains(keyword))  // Om arr[0], arr[1] eller arr[2] innhåller sökord....
                                    {
                                        foreach (string s in item)  // Skriv ut varje arr[i] i det elementet(item) (dvs hela den loggen)
                                        {
                                            Console.WriteLine("\t" + s);
                                        }
                                        Console.WriteLine("");
                                        anyFound = true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (!anyFound)
                                Console.WriteLine("\tSearchword couldn't be found.");
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            Console.WriteLine("\tThese are the current posts in Logbook.\n ");

                            foreach (var item in logBook)  //För varje element(item) i Listan(logBook) dvs (arr[i])
                            {
                                foreach (string element in item)  //För varje element(element) i arr[i] dvs (arr[0], arr[1], arr[2])
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + element);
                                }
                                    Console.WriteLine("");
                            }
                            break;

                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("\tChoose from menu 1 - 4");
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            go = false;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");  //Estetisk för att användaren ska få ny rad innan meddelandet.
                Console.WriteLine("\tChoose from menu by using number 1 - 4"); //Aktiveras om användaren knappar in annat än heltal.
            }
```